# How to set a Tkinter widget to a monospaced, platform independent font?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, ttk, monospace

It's said [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html) in the section  *Standard Fonts*:

> Particularly for more-or-less standard user interface elements, each
>   platform defines specific fonts that should be used. Tk encapsulates
>   many of these into a standard set of fonts that are always available,
>   and of course the standard widgets use these fonts. This helps
>   abstract away platform differences.

And then in the predefined fonts list there is:

> **`TkFixedFont`** `A standard fixed-width font.`

This also corresponds with what I could find here on the standard ways of choosing a monospaced, platform independent font in `Tkinter` like for example stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42332342/4465708).

Alas, when I try to do this on my own, like with the simple code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Fixed.TButton", font=("TkFixedFont", 16))

button = ttk.Button(text="Some monospaced text, hopefully", style="Fixed.TButton")
frame.grid()
button.grid(sticky="news")
button.configure(text="I don't quite like this font.")
```

what I get is this:

[image: TkFixedFont, size 16]

That doesn't look like monospaced to me, so I check what exactly `Tkinter` translates `TkFixedFont` into on my platform with:

```
from tkinter import font
font.nametofont("TkFixedFont").actual()
```

and the answer is:

```
{'family': 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'size': 9, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'underline': 0, 'overstrike': 0}
```

So how does `DejaVu Sans Mono` look like?

[image: DejaVu Sans Mono, size 16]

The *Tkdocs.com tutorial* quoted above has also a section on *Named Fonts* and there it says:

> the names **`Courier`**, `Times`, and `Helvetica` are guaranteed to be supported
>   (and mapped to an appropriate **monospaced**, serif, or sans-serif font)

So I try with:

```
style.configure("Courier.TButton", font=("Courier", 16))
button.configure(style="Courier.TButton")
```

and now finally I get a monospaced result:

[image]

Admittedly, it's `Courier New` and not `DejaVu Sans Mono` that my platform chooses as the standard monospaced font, but that's at least something, right? But shouldn't `TkFixedFont` just work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Standard fonts (including `TkFixedFont`) can only be given as a plain string, not as a tuple. I.e. `font='TkFixedFont'` works, while `font=('TkFixedFont',)` (note the parentheses and comma) will not.

This seems to be the general case. I tried it with both `Tkinter.Button` and `ttk.Style`.

For styles that means:

```
import Tkinter
import ttk

# will use the default (non-monospaced) font
broken = ttk.Style()
broken.configure('Broken.TButton', font=('TkFixedFont', 16))

# will work but use Courier or something resembling it
courier = ttk.Style()
courier.configure('Courier.TButton', font=('Courier', 16))

# will work nicely and use the system default monospace font
fixed = ttk.Style()
fixed.configure('Fixed.TButton', font='TkFixedFont')
```

Tested to work with Python 2.7 on both Linux and Windows [**Edit:** and it's still true as of today on Python 3.x]

Bottom line is that the code in the question will work perfectly fine if just the parentheses around `"TkFixedFont"` were removed.

Comment: I'm not as well versed in TkInter intricacies now as I used to be this 4 months ago but a quick look [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html) confirmed my worry you're talking about tkinter.Button (which can be initialized with `font` option) and I asked about tkinter.tkk.Button which doesn't have it. Probably I should've made it more clear in the title that the question was about ttk widgets

Comment: wondering how to use `Fixed.Button` and specify the size?

Comment: @nycynik You should post a new question, referencing this answer in the body via hyperlink. PS I've been "tinkering" with `tkinter` for a year and with more learning from answers like above, it just keeps getting better :)