# how to use pyfiglet in tkinter text widget in proper format

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use pyfiglet in tkinter's text widget but it get all jumbled up
what I want is in below image, and this below image is of terminal
[image]

But instead of that what I'm getting is
[image: jumbled image]

so if Anyone knows how to fix this please let me know
Appreciate your efforts and thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use a fixed-width font.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comment ( by Bryan Oakley ) you need to use a fixed-width font. But be aware that not all in tkinter listed fixed-width fonts behave as such if used as fonts in tkinter. In addition to that on my system the TkFixedFont seems not to have a bold version and doesn't resize. The code below is a bit modified code you find in a link listed at the code begin. After making the figlet text blue and bold I have got what you want:

[image]

```
# http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm
import tkinter as tk
from   tkinter.font import Font

class Pad(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.buttonFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.buttonFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.bold_btn  = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Bold" , command=self.make_bold)
        self.bold_btn.pack(side="left")
        self.blue_btn  = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Blue" , command=self.make_blue)
        self.blue_btn.pack(side="left")
        self.clear_btn = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Clear", command=self.allclear)
        self.clear_btn.pack(side="left")

        # Creates a normal and a bold font
        # self.norm_font = Font(font="TkFixedFont", size=14) # no SIZE choice in TkFixedFont? # family="Bitstream Vera Sans Mono" ,weight= , slant= , underline= , overstrike= )
        # self.bold_font = Font(font="TkFixedFont", size=10, weight="bold") # no BOLD version in TkFixedFont? 
        self.norm_font = Font(family="Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", size=14) # font= ,weight= , slant= , underline= , overstrike= )
        self.bold_font = Font(family="Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", size=14, weight="bold") # no BOLD version in TkFixedFont? 

        self.text = tk.Text(self)

        self.text.insert("end", 
        "\n"
        "  Select part of text and then click 'Blue' or/and 'Bold' ...              \n"
        "\n"
        "   ---   ---   ---   ---         ---   ---   ---               ---   ---   \n"
        "  |   | |   | |   |   |         |     |     |   | |\  | |\  | |     |   |  \n"
        "  |-+-  |   | |-+-    |          -+-  |     |-+-| | + | | + | |-+-  |-+-   \n"
        "  |     |   | |  \    |             | |     |   | |  \| |  \| |     |  \   \n"
        "         ---                     ---   ---                     ---           " 
        )
        self.text.focus()
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # configuring tags called NORM, BLUE, BOLD
        self.text.tag_configure("BOLD", font=self.bold_font)
        self.text.tag_configure("NORM", font=self.norm_font)
        self.text.tag_configure("BLUE", background="blue", foreground="white")
        self.text.tag_add(
            'NORM', # the tag is given the name/id 'NORM' 
            '1.0',  # 1.0 -> first line, first char (lines count from 1, characters from 0)
            'end')  # end of the entire text
        #                                 

    def make_bold(self):
        # tk.TclError exception is raised if not text is selected
        try:
            self.text.tag_remove("NORM", "sel.first", "sel.last")        
            # self.text.tag_remove("BLUE", "sel.first", "sel.last")        
            self.text.tag_add(   "BOLD", "sel.first", "sel.last")        
        except tk.TclError:
            pass

    def make_blue(self):
        # tk.TclError exception is raised if not text is selected
        try:
            # self.text.tag_remove("NORM", "sel.first", "sel.last")        
            # self.text.tag_remove("BOLD", "sel.first", "sel.last")        
            self.text.tag_add(   "BLUE", "sel.first", "sel.last")        
        except tk.TclError:
            pass

    def allclear(self):
        self.text.tag_remove("NORM",  "1.0", 'end')
        self.text.tag_remove("BOLD",  "1.0", 'end')
        self.text.tag_remove("BLUE",  "1.0", 'end')
        self.text.tag_add(   "NORM",  "1.0", "end")


def demo():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.minsize(width=1056, height=256)
    root.maxsize(width=1056, height=300)
    root.title("PORT SCANNER")
    Pad(root).pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

P.S. There are questionmarks I have placed in the comments in the above code and **there is some info about similar problems I run into with the fixed font issue already myself** available on stackoverflow:

[How to set a Tkinter widget to a monospaced, platform independent font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731746/how-to-set-a-tkinter-widget-to-a-monospaced-platform-independent-font)

[String alignment in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128270/string-alignment-in-tkinter/42332342#42332342) .

So don't be surprised if the code above doesn't work for you and you have to see which font choice works as expected on your system.

See [List available font families in `tkinter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614027/list-available-font-families-in-tkinter#39614028) for how to get in `tkinter` a list of available font families.